# Why do VBA data types have seemingly random constant values assigned to them in the object browser?

Tags: vba

In the VBA Object Browser, then VBA library, under class VbVarType is a list of all the possible data types a user can utilize.  For some reason these data types have random numbers associated with them and they aren't the default values.  For example, vbDouble = 5, vbString = 8, etc.

Comment: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/Enums.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[About Type Variant](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251448.aspx)

> The Variant data type is the data type for all variables that are not explicitly declared as some other type. A Variant is a special data type that can contain any kind of data except fixed-length String data.

This means if you write e.g. `Dim x` without defining any data type then `x` is considered to be a `Variant`. It is equivalent with `Dim x As Variant`.

`VbVarType` enum contains constants which are used to identify the different data-types which can be stored in variable of type `Variant`. Use `VarType` function to get the `Variant` Sub-Type.

```
Sub VarTypeTest()
    Dim testVariant As Variant

    testVariant = True
    Debug.Print VarType(testVariant) ' print 11 which equals to VBA.VbVarType.vbBoolean

    testVariant = "Hi"
    Debug.Print VarType(testVariant) ' print 8 which equals to VBA.VbVarType.vbString

    testVariant = 123
    Debug.Print VarType(testVariant) ' print 8 which equals to VBA.VbVarType.vbInteger

    ' etc.
End Sub
```